# Power bi : How to make a filter to filter on company with different categories. I have field "Company", "Company Category" , "Sales"

Tags: powerbi

Power bi : How to make a filter to filter on company with different categories. I have field "Company", "Company Category" , "Sales"

i want to filter on each top3 for each category by sales.
That means filter on: 
category A : Top 1 - 3
category B : Top 1 - 3

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and what results you expect?

Comment: Maybe the Hierarchy slicer might do the trick:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820